# how does image/file caching work in ionic?

Tags: android, image, caching, cordova-plugins

I have an ionic app that uses $cordovaImagePicker, $cordovaFile and $cordovaCamera to store images from the device to the local application directory.  The workflow for this process is as follows:

1. Get image from the gallery(using $cordovaImagePicker) or take a photo (using $cordovaCamera).
2. Store the file URI to a $scope variable.
3. When the user decides to save the image, I use the $cordovaFile check the file if it already exist in cordova.file.dataDirectory and remove it if it does.  Then, I move the file from the cache directory to the cordova.file.dataDirectory.

I am able to correctly save the image without any errors in cordova and after the update, my app re-direct to another screen with a different controller.  Now the problem that I have is that when I change the image and try to view it, my app still shows the old image.  However, if I close my application and then reopen and try to view the image again, it already shows the new image.  So this seems to be a caching problem. My code in the routing controller is as follows:

```
.state('app.product', {
url: '/app.product',
  cache: false,
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'master_data/views/mainProductInformation.html',
        controller: 'MainProductInformationController'
    }
  }
  })
  .state('app.productdetail', {
    url: '/productdetail',
    cache: false,
    params: {
        productDetail: null
    },
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl : 'master_data/views/detailedProductInformation.html',
            controller : 'DetailedProductInformationController',
        }
    }
})
```

The app goes back to app.product from app.productdetail.  I thought the cache:false would solve the caching problem but it does not.  Anyone has an idea on what the problem is?

Comment: I have the exact same problem... were you able to solve it?

Comment: try to force reload of image by attaching a query parameter when assigning the value to the image variable.  
                    if ($scope.RecordData[i].thumbnail) {
                        $scope.RecordData[i].thumbnailreloaded = $scope.RecordData[i].thumbnail + "?" + new Date().getTime();
                    }